# Обособленное определение

Tags: пунктуация

Просто хотелось бы уточнить кое-что.
**"Обычно ужасно застенчивая, она впервые мне улыбнулась".** Можно ли таким образом построить предложение? Теоретически можно, но достаточно ли это удачный макет? И не ошибся ли я ненароком, поставив запятую? Давно не встречал подобные предложения в тексте, а некоторые правила русского языка уже из головы вылетели.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все абсолютно верно, и запятая ставится. Во-первых, определение относится к личному местоимению, во-вторых, ясно видно обстоятельственное значение: "будучи ужасно застенчивой..."

Comment: Большое спасибо за быстрый ответ.